# What does jmeter do if no response is received?

Tags: jmeter

i send  10 requests to the server which was recorded by blazemeter chrome plugin.
some of them are signalr requests that have connection token values created runtime.

signalr requests are

signalr/negotiate?..

signalr/connect?

signalr/start?

signalr/abort?

if i dont use regular expression extractor for correlation, the signalr request has wrong responses and test will fail.
if i use correlation, some interesting results are present.
if i use it only in **signalr/start** it will pass, the other signalr's will fail.

if i add the connectionParameter to the **signalr/connect**... request. it will do nothing and test will not continue and **not finished**. So, i wonder if Jmeter dont send the request or any response is received. in view result tree listener, the request is not seen in this case.
What will Jmeter do if a response is not send by server?
or any other information that i dont know related to **signalr/connect**.. issue?

Answer (score 0):

> What will Jmeter do if a response is not send by server

When it comes to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers JMeter will wait for response for the time defined in the "Timeouts" section of the aforementioned HTTP Request sampler

[image]

Blank values mean "no timeout" so JMeter will wait either forever or until the socket timeout defined in the underlying JVM or OS is exceeded.

With regards to SignalR most probably you need to use [WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) plugin, I don't think there is a way to record these requests using whatever JMeter recording solution currently available in the market so consider inspecting the traffic from your browser to the backend using either [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: i tried a lot of things you suggested. i cant get the response after sending the signalr/connect.. request. i look at the differences using wireshark, with a chrome browser and jmeter. i didnt see a major difference. i want to ask 2 questions for this problem.
 

1) there is a parameter named as "tid" and a value starting with 162... (probably a time value). do these two affect the result? 
2) do we have to use websocket samplers plugin. is it an obligation or an advice for signalr